# How to do arrow and not equal like this

Tags: intellij-idea, kotlin

[How to do arrow and not equal like this in Intellij IDEA?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UWcmx.jpg)

Get it from this video 
https://youtu.be/X1RVYt2QKQE?t=13m18s

Comment: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/Support+for+Ligatures+in+Editor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download and install [FiraCode Font](https://github.com/tonsky/FiraCode) hosted on *github*.

Or any font using [ligatures](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/Support+for+Ligatures+in+Editor)

Comment: In case it is not clear, after installing the font, you'll need to make the settings change in Settings > Editor > Font